# apply codes to all controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have a simple code where i place it in my controller's constructor

```
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
$this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

i use this code for the safety of logout. my question is, Is there a way to put/declare my code as global for each of my controllers? because it will be hard to hard code everything on each controller's constructor.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: create a [Core controller](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html) and extend others from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like all the answers but the best approach is to use hooks.
First Add this to your hooks.php

```
 $hook['display_override'] = array(
    'class'    => 'RouteProcess',
    'function' => 'afterroute',
    'filename' => 'RouteProcess.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params'   => array()
 );
```

Then go to hooks/ folder and create RoutesProcess.php
Create the file below:

```
class RouteProcess{
function afterroute(){
    $this->CI =&get_instance();
     $this->CI->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    $this->CI->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
    echo $this->CI->output->get_output();
}
}
```

The good thing about this is it does not require __construct() of your controller to be called which can be overridden.
This will be called no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a Core Controller might be good but it will apply to each and every controller in your App the problem is, what if you have a public page which you don't want to apply that settings.

I suggest creating a controller in your Controllers folder and create it in a way you like.

example:

**Parent admin controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
      $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
    }
}
```

**Controller to inherit from the admin**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    include APPPATH.'controllers/admin.php';
    class Dashboard extends Admin {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

observe the  `include APPPATH.'controllers/admin.php';` and `class Dashboard extends Admin {` you need to include the admin controller so that you can extend it.

Comment: avoid the `parent::__construct();` function http://stackoverflow.com/a/30257004/1418750

Answer (score 1):

You can use CI hooks, and use `post_controller_constructor` hook point to call hook method and add headers in hook .

Integration details available on user guide [click here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could extends the default CI_Controller via the core directory

in application/core/MY_Controller.php: (the MY_ part is defined in your config.php)

```
class BaseController extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
      $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
    }
}
```

Then in your controllers use:

```
class ControllerXYZ extends BaseController {
    //your code
}
```

If you have controllers which don't need the functionality from BaseController, just don't extend from basecontroller, but from CI_Controller:

```
class ControllerXYZ extends CI_Controller {
    //your code without the headers set
}
```

This also has the advantage of deduplicating more code that each controller needs, for example checking if someone is logged in, you could make it like so:

```
class BaseController extends CI_Controller {

      public function __construct() {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
          $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");

          if(!$this->session->userdata('loggedIn') === True) {
              redirect('/loginpage');
          }
      }
}
```

See https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html for more information.